# Rotational Scaling

Tags: python, mesh

So, i'm making a custom add on. The nutshell of it is that I want to spawn cameras on a sphere segment of arbitrary angle. the trick is generating the curve.

So, lets say I have this segment of a sphere:
[image]

is there a good operation/set of operations so that i get something like this:[image]

I know i can model it, but because this is for an addon, the process has to be somewhat programmatic, and not create mesh distortion. For example, the deleting method wouldn't cut it, and neither would weighted rotation:

[image]

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: why not delete the vertices in order?  http://prntscr.com/jtsqyw

Comment: Because all verts have to remain. Im using the verts as info for an operation, so they need to stick around

Comment: Also, fyi, for anyone in the future, i do know you can probably grab the vertex coordinates one by one, and use that coordinate information to just solve for their final position. But im curious to see if there's a better way to do it